# Python find first network hop

Tags: python, networking, routes

I need to find the first network hop is in a python program on Linux.  I can't just depend on the default gateway being the first hop, because some of the network software on the box may (or may not) insert catch all routes:

`0.0.0.0/1`
`128.0.0.0/1`

I've thought about popen'ing a `tracepath -m 1 <some ip>` and parsing the output, but I dislike depending on the format of the output of another program.  Reading the routing table from /proc and applying routing logic to it I think is a little beyond my scripting abilities, though I will likely try it at some point.  Is there a an easier way (has someone else already invented-this-wheel in a module I'm not aware of)?

Comment: I think your objection to reading traceroute/tracepath is overcautious. These sorts of applications almost never change their output format and traceroute is ubiquitous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do the "catch all" routes do? If they are simply gateway routes, doing a route lookup would still work. You can do something like:

```
$ ip route get <ip> | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

This would print the gateway address for an off-link route:

```
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8 | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
192.168.0.1
```

... or the interface name for an on-link route:

```
$ ip route get 192.168.0.2 | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
eth0
```

And by the way (as my answer implies) I agree with the comment that the principle of *not* relying on an external program is overcautious in this case. =) I doubt that the output of `ip` will change.

Personally I'd use the route lookup since `tracepath` or `traceroute` would rely on the 1st hop host actually sending you the `TTL expired` ICMP message (it might drop it). I don't know what your use case is though.

If you need a python library to do this, I'd look into [libdnet](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I didn't know iproute2 had the `ip route get` that is really handy. Thank you! @Mike

Comment: @tMC, no problem. I just noticed that this won't work for local routes. (the field you want is offset by one) So I guess you'd be stuck parsing the output. A regex might work for this.

Comment: I tried...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954738/python-linux-route-table-lookup